# I can't log into my account

Tags: pokemon-go

I don't know my email that I used to create my Pokemon go account. Before it just logged me into my account and I count start playing the game. I hit the log into another account by accident and now it just goes to that screen and I can't get back to the game.

Comment: Well, you need to know your login info. If you don't know your login info, then it sounds like you won't be able to log in.

Comment: See second answer in linked question